# Examples of Zend_Framework based apps

Tags: zend-framework, open-source

Do you know any open source applications based on Zend Framework, good for reference purposes?

Here are some I know:

- [ZFPlanet](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet)
- [Pastebin](http://github.com/weierophinney/pastebin)
- [Postr](http://github.com/bradley-holt/postr)
- [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/svn)
- [Digitalus CMS](http://digitaluscms.com/)
- [Storefront](http://code.google.com/p/zendframeworkstorefront/)
- [joobsbox](http://www.joobsbox.com/)

Did I missed something interested?

Current version of ZF is 1.10.7.
The most up to date is ZFPlanet, which reqiures 1.10.3

Feel free to update.
*One condition:* complete source codes for working applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomato CMS is powered by Zend Framework

[Tomato CMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Two great ones are:

1. [DASPRiD](http://www.dasprids.de/) - Ben Scholzen released the [source-code](http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk/) for his blog as part of a series on modern app architecture. Well worth study as examples of dependency injection, service architecture, models/mappers, even using Phing for build.
2. Dodo - an open-source todo list by Greg Wessels. A great example of module-based app using layout-switching via plugin and an API module.

Note: Previously Dodo was at http://blog.threadaffinity.com/dodo-downloads/ but now I see no sign of threadaffinity.com at all. If anyone has a new link, I'll update the answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

[TweetGT](http://tweetgt.funkymongoose.com/) is a extremely simple Twitter message sender. Source code is here: http://github.com/akrabat/TweetGT

Answer (score 1):

There is my blog, in which I demonstrate many ZF components, especially those I've contributed, like Zend_Application, Zend_Tag_Cloud and so on. The source is freely available at http://site.svn.dasprids.de/

Answer (score 1):

Content management framework based on ZF (1.1x.x) with installer and documentation: http://singularcore.com.

Answer (score 1):

very good, easy to install

http://www.dotkernel.com/

There are [Zend based applications](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14134), some links are broken but ...

CMS Built upon the Zend Framework

http://www.centurion-project.org/

http://www.pimcore.org/

http://www.dubsite.net/

http://tiki.org/Community

Answer (score 0):

There was jotbug for a while, but it's not available on google code at the moment:

http://code.google.com/p/jotbug/

http://www.ohloh.net/p/jotbug

Oh, and ZFDebug http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/ (which is actually a zf plugin, not a whole application, but still...)