# Open source projects using Doctrine ORM

Tags: open-source, symfony1, doctrine

Following [Examples of Zend_Framework based apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531490/examples-of-zend-framework-based-apps) I'd like to ask:

Do you know any open source projects using Doctrine ORM, good for reference purposes?

What I recall:

- [ZFPlanet](http://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet)
- [Sympal](http://www.sympalphp.org/) (Symfony based CMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example is the diem CMS ([diem-project.org](http://diem-project.org/)) or Siwapp ([siwapp.org](http://www.siwapp.org/))

Answer (score 2):

LiteCommerce shopping cart project is also based on Doctrine 2 ORM: http://www.litecommerce.com