# Create Zend extensible application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm looking for a way to create zend-based application (web store) which I would extend by plugins in the future. For now I have base functionality (browsing products, make orders etc).

What I need is make possibility to attach plugins to this app. By "plugin" I mean some static files structure in sepearated directory. One of plugins, which I want to write in future is allegro(polish eBay like)-integration  tool. it would operate on existing models (user, product etc). It needs to have their own controller which would be executed in backend; Some other should be like public-accessible simple gallery for front-end. Some of other plugins should be able to attach content on previously definied spots in view.

I have no idea how can I reach this. Every of these plugins should have their own directory and It's very important;

Maybe there is some free extensible zend-based CMS? what would be yours choice?
Please for ideas and thanks for help

Comment: Why to extend it ? Can't you have plugin that can hook to zend ?

Comment: You mention plugins, but at first glance, I'd say you're looking for modules, or simply: your own _additional_ library, which you can just add to your application.ini file

Comment: `(browsing products, make orders etc)` are not zend plugins

Comment: @Sahal: I know, that's why I think the OP is looking for modules: browsing products etc... can be done using an additional controller (or even just an extra action in the main controller), but since the OP wants them in separate directories: modules are what he's looking for

Comment: Yaaah, I understood after reading the question second time :).

Comment: ok, i think that I will use Sahal's way, but i can't figure one situation. I have f.e. modules: gallery and event-calendar. I want to make 2 simple menu snippets that will be visible in every page (random photo and small calendar). If I will be currenty in product module, nothing there would be on menu, and after go to page that will use gallery module, gallery snippet will be visible and calendar not. what then? (sry4lang)

Comment: It will be hard with ZF. Because it isn't WP and modules have close connection. There you can find http://stackoverflow.com/q/3531490/949273 list of Open Source ZF project, so you can study them first ... try with tomato cms.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `zend module`. Each module will be having independent functionality.

Module structure is below

```
zf2-tutorial/
    /module
        /Album
            /config
            /src
                /Album
                    /Controller
                    /Form
                    /Model
            /view
                /album
                    /album
```

Likewise you can have modules like `Oerder`, `Payment`, `User` etc etc.

And you can create some `interface` to communicate through modules.

Below link will help you

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.module-manager.intro.html

Comment: thanks for answer, but what i need is build extensible application. for example i have product page, and i'll need plugin in future which will change display method of product (so it will include some other css and js scripts). Some other plugins (i should name it extension, do I?) should be only controller with some additional modules, (but still ableiable to use existing models) that will be accessible from admin-side module with some individual settings etc.  If I will build all extensions on module structure like yours and I will put some content to menu in that, it will be not visible

Comment: if i will move to other controller in my browser ;(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ZF2, then modules are the way to go, as EVERYTHING in ZF2 can be a module. 
Check out http://modules.zendframework.com/ for an idea of what's available. Whats more is that you can drop a module into your application, try it out and then remove it if you dont think its right for your project. Everything about a module can be modified and modules should provide hooks that your other modules can listen to.
Evan Coury (who wrote the core of the ModuleManager for zf2) has been working on https://github.com/speckcommerce which will probably cover alot of what you need